# how to monitor mesos frameworks

Tags: monitoring, mesos, mesosphere

from Mesos web UI under frameworks there is a list of running and terminated frameworks which I want to monitor periodically (save the list to a database ,etc.) 
I am wondering if there is a log file for such list , API , etc. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All events that happen in the Mesos cluster are captured in the Mesos master log. It means by parsing and analysing the log, you can reconstruct cluster state at any point of time.

Mesos WebUI is based on a `/state.json` Master endpoint. In Mesos 0.23 a new endpoint `/state-summary` is introduced. It provides less information, but also needs less time to return. I think one of those will give you what you need.